# TYPO3 uses crop images how can I avoid this

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use the `ws_Flexslider` plugin for display a slider on my TYPO3 page.

Problem is that the plugin uses croped pictures. Is it possible to use non croped pictures?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Entry.html` partial you have this line which renders your image :

`<f:image src="{item.falImage.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1" title="{item.falImage.originalResource.title}" alt="{item.falImage.originalResource.alternative}" width="{settings.maxwidth}" height="{settings.maxheight}" />`

You can set the `settings.maxwidth` and `settings.maxheight` in you typoscript constants to get the desired behavior.

Comment: and then the original uploaded file is displayed

Comment: and what should I set as values?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247205/typo3-flexslider-should-user-original-image-and-not-cropped-one
The value that should be set.... well, that is up to you to decide what value seems good. You have to set up a value that seems a good compromise between the weight and the quality of the resulting reduced image.