# typo3 flexslider should user original image and not cropped one

Tags: typo3, flexslider, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

In my typo3 7.6.19 Website I want to user the flexslider plugin. 
That works fine, my problem is that the image is a cropped one and not the original file I uploaded.

How can I change it to use the original picture?

Thanks in advance

Comment: cropped or resized?

Comment: cropped files is this `fileadmin/_processed_/8/7/csm_IMG_4066_7a387be0fc.jpg`

Comment: maybe I explained myself badly. the processed file is resized (i.e. it looks like the original image, but with different dimensions) or cropped (i.e. a piece of the image has been cut).
Can you upload a preview of the two images (original and processed)?

Comment: its a resized image. absolute small. Original one has 2550px width. the displayed one is 600px and absolute not clear (pixle collection ;) )

Comment: I see that the plugin sets a TypoScript constant `plugin.tx_wsflexslider.maxwidth=800px` Could you check your value?

Comment: That makes the trick. Thanks! Will you post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin sets up a TypoScript constant

```
plugin.tx_wsflexslider.maxwidth=800px
```

You can modify this value in your TypoScript template (Module Template > Constant Editor > select "PLUGIN.TX_WSFLEXSLIDER"

About your other problem that is artifacts in the reduced image, I think that when resizing an image from 2550px to 800px, it is probable that the quality will be reduced :) You could check those settings in Install Tool >All Configuration > Image Processing [GFX] and see if you can improve them.

A last word: I would not use images of 2550px, it seems that they will be very heavy! I would try to set a compromise (e.g. `plugin.tx_wsflexslider.maxwidth=1200px`).

You could also evalutate the extension EXT:image_autoresize https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/image_autoresize/
to automatically resize the images when uploading them and limit the weight or dimensions of the images that your editor will upload.

From this answer [typo3 uses crop images how can I avoid this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631881/typo3-uses-crop-images-how-can-i-avoid-this) I see that (of course) you can also modify the partial that renders the image and avoid using the TypoScript constants at all, but for the reasons I mentioned above, I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 10.4.x and ws_slider 0.9.8, it was not a constant but:

```
<f:image image="{item.foregroundMedia.0}" maxWidth="600" />
```

in

```
Resources/Private/Partials/Item/Flexslider.html
```